# Stripe card element is not visible on the form

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, stripe-payments, dom-manipulation

I am new to angularjs and just trying to integrate stripe api of version 3 in my angular app. I tried to follow the steps given in the stripe site. Now the problem is that in stripe site whole code is based on plain js or jquery. I tried to put the whole js code from stripe into my angular controller and it loads fine, but the problem is that card element remains blank in ui form, plus i am not getting any kind of error on console.

Here is my controller code and html code:

```
myapp.controller('paymentCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) 
{
  var stripe = Stripe('abcdedfght');
  var elements = stripe.elements();
  var card = elements.create('card', 
  {
    hidePostalCode: true,
    style: {
            base: {
                    iconColor: '#F99A52',
                    color: '#32315E',
                    lineHeight: '48px',
                    fontWeight: 400,
                    fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", sans-serif',
                    fontSize: '15px',
                    '::placeholder': {
                                        color: '#CFD7DF',
                                      }
                  },
            }
  });
  card.mount('#card-element');

  function setOutcome(result) 
  {
    var successElement = document.querySelector('.success');
    var errorElement = document.querySelector('.error');
    successElement.classList.remove('visible');
    errorElement.classList.remove('visible');
    if (result.token) 
    {
      // Use the token to create a charge or a customer
      // https://stripe.com/docs/charges
      successElement.querySelector('.token').textContent = result.token.id;
      successElement.classList.add('visible');
    } 
    else if (result.error) 
    {
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      errorElement.classList.add('visible');
    }
  }

  card.on('change', function(event) 
  {
    setOutcome(event);
  });

  document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) 
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = document.querySelector('form');
    var extraDetails = {
                        name: form.querySelector('input[name=cardholder-name]').value,
                        address_zip: form.querySelector('input[name=address-zip]').value
                      };
    stripe.createToken(card, extraDetails).then(setOutcome);
  });

}]);
```

HTML file for the angularjs state:

```
<div ng-controller='paymentCtrl'>
<form>
  <div class="group">
    <label>
      <span>Name</span>
      <input name="cardholder-name" class="field" placeholder="Jane Doe" />
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>Phone</span>
      <input class="field" placeholder="(123) 456-7890" type="tel" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label>
      <span>Card</span>
      <div id="card-element" class="field"></div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Pay $25</button>
  <div class="outcome">
    <div class="error" role="alert"></div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

I tried to change this form to directive also, but it still doesn't work.

Note:  is loaded in a file called main.html which is basically the entry point of my angularjs app.

Edit: After trying various times i found that card is mounting properly and card input is sent when i post, so problem is whatever i am entering on card input is not getting displayed.

Is it because I am on localhost and https is not there?

Answer (score 20):

It should work fine under http with your test key, only on your production system https is mandatory.

I also use angular (4) and I had similar problems with the card input not showing. It turned out that in my case it was just a styling issue. By playing around with the styles, I got the card input field showing up. In the end I added these style elements (shown inline for clarity):

```
  <div>
    <div style="width: 30em" #stripecardelement id="card-element"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <!-- Used to display Element errors -->
    <span style="width: 30em; height: 2em; letter-spacing: 0em" id="card-errors" role="alert"></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. `style="width: 30em"` was the solution

Answer (score 0):

I guess several developers are running into this when setting up the demo for the first time. The foolowing check *might* help unless there are other issues:

Ensure that the client actually connects to https://js.stripe.com/v3/ and that the public key is correct. If the connection fails, Payment details (card-element) will not render.

Open the inspect windows to look for any errors on the client side.